# Arguments in shell scripting

Tags: bash, awk

I actually want to initialise FS as "=" and store the second field in some text file.SO i have written a shell script for it.Here the BASH is considering that $2 refers to the second field in the input text file and $1 means the name of the input text file.How does bash differentiate between AWk arguments and shell arguments??

THIs is the shellscript and it works!!

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";}{print $2 >> "a.txt"}' $1
exit
```

Comment: It doesn't. The single quotes make the shell ignore the contents. It doesn't look for variables there at all. That's what single quotes do.

Comment: `$1` is a shell variable, the first positional parameter. `$2` is an awk construct that refers to the value ($) of the second field (2) in the current record.

Comment: The same result is possible without awk: `cut -d= -f2 $1`. When you want everything after the equal-sign, even a possible second one, use `-f2-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire string between the single quotes are passed verbatim to `awk`. Since `$1` was not between single quotes, `bash` interprets it and substitutes the value of the first argument.

(By the way, it's a good practice to always use double quotes for variables, as in `"$1"`. Otherwise, if `$1` had spaces in it, it will expand to multiple words.)